# Can't extract integer from cursor after preforming sqlite query in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursors

I'm working on an small android app that maintains a small database of tools which I lend out to other people.

As part of the app, I am incorporating an sqllite database, where I am having a bit of trouble performing queries and working with cursors once the queries have been executed.

The code in question is as follows:

```
    String COLUMN_NAME = "toolName";
    String[] columns = { COLUMN_NAME };
    String selection = COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {tool};

    Cursor cursor = mToolDb.query(ToolStatisticContract.ToolStatisticEntry.TABLE_NAME, columns, 
    selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);

    return Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
```

The contract for the database is as follows:

```
    public class ToolStatisticContract {
        public static final class ToolStatisticEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tooltable";
        public static final String COLUMN_TOOL_NAME = "toolName";
        public static final String COLUMN_LIFESPAN = "lifespan";
        public static final String COLUMN_USAGE = "usageTime";
    }
}
```

I am essentially trying to extract out the value from COLUMN_USAGE, which seems to be producing errors with regards to parsing the value to an integer. The value in the COLUMN is actually an integer typecasted as a String from a previous segment of code, so I'm fairly certain the error is encompasssed with the code snippets above.

Thanks again in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

> The code in question is as follows

The net SQL statement is something like:

```
SELECT toolName FROM tooltable WHERE toolName = ?
```

And there is no column with index 3, since you are only returning 1 column.

You need to:

- Have `usageTime` in your column list (`COLUMNS`)
- Move the `Cursor` to a valid row (as it initially is positioned before the first row)
- Pass `getInteger()` the value that lines up with `COLUMNS` to retrieve `usageTime`

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your reply. So from my (limited) understanding, I should modify COLUMNS [] such that only usageTime is present since that is the column I actually need.

Comment: In terms of moving the Cursor to a valid row, isn't that already being done by the database.query function?

Comment: @GoatHerder no, when you get the cursor it is positioned before the first row. This is because a cursor containing no rows is valid as a cursor.

Comment: RIGHT! Okay so basically I after the query, I have to move it down to the first row before I can call getInteger() or anything else. Am I right to say this?

Comment: @GoatHerder, yep I've added an answer showing how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following. This uses **`null`** instead of columns, which will get all columns (i.e. resolves to `SELECT * FROM table`). It checks that a row has been returned and only then does it try to get the data. It also closes the cursor (you should close a cursor when done with it). It uses `cursor.getInt()` to get the integer value rather than convert it from a string to int. It assumes that you'll only get 1 row (*if no rows then 0 will be returned*).

```
int returnvalue = 0;
String COLUMN_NAME = "toolName";
String[] columns = { COLUMN_NAME };
String selection = COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
String[] selectionArgs = {tool};

Cursor cursor = mToolDb.query(ToolStatisticContract.ToolStatisticEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, 
selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    returnvalue = cursor.getInt(2);
    //or returnvalue = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
}
cursor.close();
return returnvalue;
```

*Note! I haven't checked this just coded it from memory, so apologies for the odd mistake.*

To do the above using specific columns then you could use:-

```
String COLUMN_NAME = "toolName";
String[] columns = { COLUMN_USAGE };
String selection = COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
String[] selectionArgs = {tool};

Cursor cursor = mToolDb.query(ToolStatisticContract.ToolStatisticEntry.TABLE_NAME, columns, 
selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
```

In which case the column index would be 0 (*that is the index is according to the column's in the cursor*). However it might be better to use, the following which gets the column index according to the column's name:-

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read a single value from the database is to use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) that allows you to avoid having to handle cursor objects:

```java
String query = "SELECT usageTime FROM tooltable WHERE toolName = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { tool };
long returnvalue = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(mToolDb, query, selectionArgs);
```